# Ordeing dates in R

Tags: r, date

When I order the days in R they appear correctly like this (NZ date formatted aa dd,mm,yyyy):

```
pHAuckOtehaStream$Date[164:175]
 [1] 7/01/00  1/02/00  7/03/00  4/04/00  2/05/00  8/06/00  4/07/00  31/07/00 5/09/00 
[10] 3/10/00  31/10/00 5/12/00
```

Which is correct, however when I plot these it is taking the dd as the order rather than the month or year the American form of dates, how can i change this? 
[image]

Comment: Check out `?as.Date` and take a look at the optional `format` argument =)

Comment: What you have are strings that happen to look like dates, so they sort alphabetically. If you want dates, you need to convert them (`as.Date(pHAuckOtehaStream$Date,format="%d/%m/%y")`).

Comment: Also, it's generally easiest work with dates in R if format is yyyy-mm-dd (standard/default for most R functions and packages that deal with dates). I usually do all my data manipulation and analysis with yyyy-mm-dd dates and then format them to match local standards only when I make a figure or export data

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to `as.Date` (as proposed in the comments) is the date parsing functions in the `lubridate` package, which parses dates stored in a character vector into a `Date` object.

```
library(lubridate)
dmy(c("7/01/00","1/02/00"))
# [1] "2000-01-07" "2000-02-01"
```